# System.InvalidCastException - two cases only one error

Tags: c#

I do not understand why my first piece of code works fine, but the second time I try to convert string to an integer. I assume it is the random function something happens with, but I do not understand what?

My last piece of code give the following error once I enter a number:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Which animal do you choose? Tiger (press 1) Wolf (press 2)");

int UserAnimal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
string PlayerName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Game live {0}! Guess a number between 1-10", PlayerName);

Random Random = new Random();
int RandomNumber = Random.Next(1, 11);
int CorrectNumber = RandomNumber;

int Guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); is different than Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey()); so it is not the exact same case.

Answer (score 2):

In the last line, you call `Console.ReadKey()`, which returns an object of the structure `System.ConsoleKeyInfo`, instead of `Console.ReadLine()`. The returned struct cannot be converted to `int` directly by calling `Convert.ToInt32()` on it.

Either change `Console.ReadKey()` into `Console.ReadLine()`, or:

```
int Guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Console.ReadKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a ConsoleKeyInfo type while [Console.Readline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a string. Convert can't cast a ConsoleKeyInfo type into an int.

Comment: Aha, perfect. Thanks for the explanation!